# How to select first td of first two rows using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, csscomb

It's a complicated one I think. Let's see if I'm wrong.
I want to select only the td which are marked as "// to be selected"
I dont want to apply styles for any other td other than the marked ones.
Please help!

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td> // to be selected
      <div>
       <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> // to be selected
      <div>
       <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> // to be selected
      <div>
       <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: How about you add a class to the `td` you want to apply styles?

Comment: The layout is generated automatically and hence I'm unable to assign a CSS class to it.

Comment: Use `td` to set styles to all  `td` elements and use `td td` to reset the styles to the nested `td` elements?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for the solution.

Comment: Could you mark my post as the answer, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `td` to set styles to all `td` elements and use `td td` to reset the styles to the nested `td` elements.

```
td {
  // styles
}

td td {
  // styles to reset the nested elements
}
```

Comment: This would colour all adjacent TD cells too, if the system were to generate any

Comment: @KaraokeStu Why that would be a problem?

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem necessarily, unless he didn't want subsequent TDs to be coloured

Answer (score 0):

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]
let tbody = table.children[0];

let trs = tbody.children



for (let i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){

  var tdhtml = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML 
  
  trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML ='selected' + tdhtml
  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td> 1<!--to be selected-->
      <div>
       <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> 2<!--to be selected-->
      <div>
       <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> 3 <!-- to be selected-->
      <div>
       <div>
        <table>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table> 
       </div>
      </div>
     </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cannot use javascript. I'm using SAP Lumira, so only custom CSS files are allowed.

Comment: show us the rest of the html for the page

Comment: Javascript is overkill for this, plus you end up with the dreaded "browser flash" as the javascript kicks in and sets the styles

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before (and in my opinion the best option), you can add a class to the `td` elements you want to select, you can also select them using specificity by using the path to those elements.

```
CSS    
table tbody tr td{
    /* your code here */
}
```

Comment: On a second thought, this may not be the best option, since this element's children will inherit the style. maybe using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to apply a CSS class to the first TD of each row in the highest level table, as follows:

```
/* Set all root TR's and the first TD element */
table>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Reset so that this doesn't cascade */
table>tbody>tr>td:first-child td {
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

Example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/0utqvhy6/